# Visual Studio crashes when trying to open up

Tags: c#, crash, visual-studio-2013

I've installed Visual Studio 2013 a few weeks ago. I played around with making some C# applications. But today when I tried to open up Visual Studio, I got the following error message: The operation could not be completed. No such interface supported.

I have tried to run it as administrator, same problem. This is the only version that's installed on my computer. I have Win 7 64 bit. Could anyone help please?

Answer (score 6):

I had this problem too on VS12. There are probably more solutions but the simplest one is to clear VisualStudio's temporary data. You can find that in C:\Users\_name\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\_version. Just delete entire version folder and it will be regenerated when you open VS.

Answer (score 1):

Try Repairing VS2013 and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and none of the other solutions fixed it for me. I needed to repair .Net 4.5.2 before it would work again.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue after a hard reboot (pulled plug). I repaired VS - did not help. 
I also noticed that some other programs also had the same problem.

I repaired .net Framework 4.5.2 - after that it seems fine...